# Can an Oracle CLOB support special characters

Tags: json, oracle, clob

I can save the special characters in CLOB. But converting it to UTF-8 is not working with my code. If it supports, what is the way to convert CLOB content to UTF-8?

Comment: Yes, a CLOB _can_ store "special characters" - it depends on the characterset your database is using. As an alternative try `NCLOB` instead

Comment: The convert is something like this `convert(inpfile,'UTF8' , 'CL8MSWIN1251')` see [this](https://community.oracle.com/thread/318901)

Comment: I could able to retrieve the records saved in special chars but if i do with clob content it is not converted to UTF-8 on retrieval

Comment: i used IOUtils class which will convert my input stream to UTF-8

Comment: IOUtils.toString(inputStream, "UTF-8")

Comment: Oracle [discourages the use of the `convert` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions034.htm); you might be seeing the reason they do so. What are your database and national character sets? If neither is UTF-8 then you might need to store the value as RAW, as the note suggests?